Removing 'Duplicate' records where some columns data is null
In my Snowflake SQL query I have an output like below, all other fields contain the same data when grouped by Column A:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Tag




A
NULL
AAAA
NULL
1


A
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC



B
DDDD
NULL
EEEE
3


B
FFFF
NULL
GGGG
4


B
HHHH
NULL
IIII
2


B
HHHH
JJJJ
IIII




The query uses both SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY clauses to remove any duplication where it exists. I'm aware that these are not true 'duplicates' but I'd like to remove the rows i've tagged as 1 and 2 as they have NULLS, so my output should look like this:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




A
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC


B
DDDD
NULL
EEEE


B
FFFF
NULL
GGGG


B
HHHH
JJJJ
IIII



I've already tried using ROW_NUMBER(), PARTITION BY, RANK() etc to eliminate the rows i don't require, but as rows tagged 3 and 4 legitimately contain NULLS it also removes them. There are no other fields (for example datetime) that i could use to order by and remove based on them.
A slimmed down example of my current query is:
SELECT
COLUMN A,
COLUMN B,
COLUMN C,
COLUMN D,
COLUMN E,
COLUMN F
FROM
(
    WITH CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN E,
        COLUMN F
        FROM
        SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SOURCE = '1'
    ),
    CTE2 AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN G,
        COLUMN H
        FROM
        SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SOURCE = '2'
    ),   
    CTE3 AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN E,
        COLUMN F
        FROM
        SOURCE_TABLE WHERE SOURCE = '3'
    ),  
    BASE_CTE AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        MAX(COLUMN E) AS COLUMN E,
        LISTAGG(COLUMN F, ', ') AS COLUMN F,
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
            COLUMN A,
            COLUMN B,
            COLUMN C,
            COLUMN D,
            COLUMN E,
            COLUMN F
            FROM
            CTE1
            UNION
            (
                SELECT
                COLUMN A,
                COLUMN B,
                COLUMN C,
                COLUMN D,
                COLUMN E,
                COLUMN F
                FROM
                CTE2
            )
            UNION
            (
                SELECT
                COLUMN A,
                COLUMN B,
                COLUMN C,
                COLUMN D,
                COLUMN E,
                COLUMN F
                FROM
                CTE3
            )
        ) GROUP BY ALL
    )
    SELECT * FROM BASE_CTE
);


Hi @Macleane, welcome , do you always want Nulls to be excluded where  SOURCE  in 1 and 2 but want  to be included if the SOURCE is 3 or 4. If yes then you can use NVL and subsite the NULL columns  with a '-' or any other hard coded value and exclude the rows if  the column contains  that value.  for ex  have this for all the columns where you want nulls to be excluded - NVL(NULLIF(TRIM(column_1) , ''), '-')  AS column_1 , and in your where clause excluded if the conditions ae met WHERE column_1 <> '-'.

If the output contains 3 rows like A AAAA NULL   NULL, A NULL BBBB   NULL and A NULL NULL   CCCC what row[s] should be removed?

Apologies but i had added in the row numbers, but for some reason they're not showing. The rows to be 'removed' are the first and the fifth rows

You can use the following approach:

Do self left join on Column A (plus add a condition here where Columns B, C, D are not equal).
Use the CASE WHEN to mark rows with 0 when left side of join is a duplicate of the right side; and with 0 otherwise.
For each row, calculate if it's a duplicate at least once (MAX(dedup) OVER(...)), and filter by it (QUALIFY ...)
Finally select only DISTINCT rows to avoid duplications.

Two notes:

This doesn't work if B, C, D are NULLs and it's the only row for the value of Column A. If that's the problem for you, it's possible to adjust the query. I didn't do it here, because I believe it will make code harder to understand and distract from the main idea.
If you meant some other/additional conditions to consider a row the duplicate, feel free to adjust definition of dedup field.

WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS col_a, NULL AS col_b, 'AAAA' AS col_c, NULL AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS col_a, 'BBBB' AS col_b, 'AAAA' AS col_c, 'CCCC' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS col_a, 'DDDD' AS col_b, NULL AS col_c, 'EEEE' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS col_a, 'FFFF' AS col_b, NULL AS col_c, 'GGGG' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS col_a, 'HHHH' AS col_b, NULL AS col_c, 'IIII' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS col_a, 'HHHH' AS col_b, 'JJJJ' AS col_c, 'IIII' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS col_a, 'AAAA' AS col_b, 'BBBB' AS col_c, 'CCCC' AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D' AS col_a, NULL AS col_b, NULL AS col_c, NULL AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS col_a, NULL AS col_b, NULL AS col_c, NULL AS col_d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'E' AS col_a, 'AAAA' AS col_b, 'BBBB' AS col_c, 'CCCC' AS col_d
  ),

processed AS (
    SELECT
      d1.col_a,
      d1.col_b,
      d1.col_c,
      d1.col_d,
      CASE
        WHEN (
            (d1.col_b IS NULL OR d1.col_b = d2.col_b)
            AND (d1.col_c IS NULL OR d1.col_c = d2.col_c)
            AND (d1.col_d IS NULL OR d1.col_d = d2.col_d)
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS dedup
      FROM data d1
    LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d1.col_a = d2.col_a AND hash(d1.col_b, d1.col_c, d1.col_d) != hash(d2.col_b, d2.col_c, d2.col_d)
    QUALIFY MAX(dedup) OVER(PARTITION BY d1.col_a, d1.col_b, d1.col_c, d1.col_d) = 0
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    col_a,
    col_b,
    col_c,
    col_d
FROM processed
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4


Thanks Kliment, this has worked for me!

u can try:
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN E,
        COLUMN F
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE 
    WHERE SOURCE = '1'
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN E,  
        COLUMN F
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE 
    WHERE SOURCE = '2'
),   
CTE3 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        COLUMN E,
        COLUMN F
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE 
    WHERE SOURCE = '3'
),
BASE_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        COLUMN A,
        COLUMN B,
        COLUMN C,
        COLUMN D,
        MAX(COLUMN E) AS COLUMN E,
        LISTAGG(COLUMN F, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN F) AS COLUMN F
    FROM (
        SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D, COLUMN E, COLUMN F FROM CTE1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D, COLUMN E, COLUMN F FROM CTE2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D, COLUMN E, COLUMN F FROM CTE3
    ) 
    GROUP BY COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D
)
SELECT 
    COLUMN A,
    COLUMN B,
    COLUMN C,
    COLUMN D,
    COLUMN E,
    COLUMN F
FROM BASE_CTE;

